# Android io.card:android-sdk warning

Tags: android

I am using Card.io v5.5.1, it works fine just a message keep showing :

```
> Task :app:stripDevDebugDebugSymbols
Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libcardioDecider.so, libcardioDecider.so.
```

I do not using NDK to develop, but I have download NDK (side by side) from SDK Tools

[image]

and this is dependency

```
implementation 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1'
```

Does anyone know what does the message means? And how can I get rid of this?